# javascript validation check on click condition from HTML

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS. Please help me resolving the issue.

```
<tr>
<td align="CENTER">
<input type="SUBMIT" onclick="validate();location=www.somethg.com" value="Update">
</td>
<td align="LEFT">
<input type="BUTTON" value="Reset&nbsp;" onclick="reset()">
</td>
</tr>
```

Above code is a small piece taken which shall validate on click and will switch to location "somethg".

But i want if validate returns false then only after pressing update it should go to that location else not. How to add this condition. No jquery please.

Comment: show `reset()` and `validate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write another function for eg.

```
function validateAndRelocate() {
  if(!validate()) {
   location.href = "www.something.com"
  }
}
```

And replace

```
<input type="SUBMIT" onclick="validateAndRelocate()" value="Update">
```

Comment: how I can pass "www.something.com" from validateAndRelocate function?

Comment: Where do you want to pass, Please elaborate.

Comment: <input type="SUBMIT" onclick="validateAndRelocate(www.somethg.com) value="Update">

Comment: function validateAndRelocate(relocationURL) {
  if(!validate()) {
   location.href = relocationURL;
  }
}